# Type mismatch for relations. SDK types do not expect to see "has_more"

Tags: typescript, notion-api

I fetch data from the notion api. I want to work with that data and have used the types "PageObjectResponse" and "PartialPageObjectResponse" from the sdk to define the responses I can get. For all the properties that are relations I get a type error:

'has_more' does not exist in type '{ type: "relation"; relation: { id: string; }[]; id: string; }'

The data looks like this:

Parent: {
id: "%60J%3D~",
type: "relation",
relation: [{ id: "a8b666cc-4c8c-4e10-b612-2eb1f968b1a4" }],
has_more: false,
},